# PHP How do i check to see if the both emails match before i can submit the form?

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

I have the below code, I want to validate the form to make sure both emails match before the for gets submitted.

The emails are on line 24 & 26
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/config.php';
$pageTitle = 'Members';
include HEADER;
?>

<?php
$fname  = "";
$lname  = "";
$email1 = "";
$email2 = "";
?>

<p>To create an account with us please fill out the form below</p>

<form action="sendRegister.php" method="get">
    First Name: <input name="new[fname]" type="text"><br>
    Last Name: <input name="new[lname]" type="text"><br>
</form>

Email : <input name="new[email1]" required="" type="email" value="<?php echo $email1;?>"><br>
Re-Enter Email : <input name="new[email2]" required="" type="email" value="<?php echo $email2;?>"><br>
Password: <input name="new[password1]" type="password"><br>
Re-enter password:<input name="new[password2]" type="password"><br>
Gender: <select name="new[gender]">
    <option value="Male">
        Male
    </option>

    <option value="Female">
        Female
    </option>
</select><br>
State of Residence:<select name="new[states]">
    <option value="NY">
        New York
    </option>

    <option value="NJ">
        New Jersey
    </option>
</select><br>
<br>
<?php 
if(isset($email1) != $email2){
echo 'please correct your email';
}
?>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
<?php 
include FOOTER;
?>
```

Comment: i always copy and paste when asked to submit address twice; so it is of little added benefit - i would always validate an email by sending the user an email to the address and getting them to reply with a specific link key.

Comment: You have an extra close tag to your form.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if(isset($email1, $email2)) {
  if($email1 != $email2){
    echo "Bad Email"
    ....
  }
}
```

You can also use javascript to do this (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp)

Comment: I agree with the PHP here however you should never rely only on client validation as this can easily be circumvented

Comment: You can `isset($email1, $email2, ...)` and it's equal to running multiple `isset`s with `&&`

Comment: @SimplyKiwi In principle I agree with you 100%. However in this case the client validation is what I like to call typo catching, making sure the user didn't do something stupid by accident. Thus, javascript validation makes a lot of sense here.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to use JavaScript for this, especially if you want it validated prior to submission, as (afaik) PHP would have to do the check upon submission, whereas you can use JavaScript to check as the submit button is clicked and depending on the result of the validation carry on.

Take a look at: [W3Schools JS Form Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp)

Comment: Why the down vote? Using PHP to validate emails is a useless click for the end user and a pointless redirect. I appreciate I didn't answer the question with a PHP centric answer, yet my answer is perfectly valid seeing as the previous answer supplied the same link.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but pure JavaScript is not the best practice here. While it is a nice as a courtesy for a user, you cannot trust client-side validation.

Comment: js can be circumvented so, php should always be used (either in addition or exclusively), and w3shools should never be linked to see http://w3fools.com (no i did not down vote)

Comment: you can use js with XMLhttpRequest and send the 2 values to an php script. the PHP script compares and send a true or false back...

Comment: I tried the codes, they do not work or may be I am not sure how to put them together.... please help

Comment: PHP has to be run on the server. You can't process this client side. As this is the case, you'll need to submit the form to your submission script amd check the emails match there. Depending on the outcome, either redirect back to the page and tell the user that they do not match, or carry on.

Comment: thank you very much.  I thought it could of been done. but you just remind me that php is server side, which i knew it slipped my mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check **before** you submit the form, you must do it with javascript.

A second possibility is: put your submitted form-values as defauld value e.g.:

```
<?php
$pass1=$_POST["pass1"];
$pass2=$_POST["pass2"];
if (isset($pass1,$pass2) && $pass1!=$pass2) echo 'Your password confirmation is not equal to your password';
echo '<form ....>';
echo '<input type="text" name="pass1" value="'.$pass1.'">';
echo '<input type="text" name="pass2" value="'.$pass2.'">';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Comment: This is an example. you can't copy-paste it... it's just to demonstrate how you can pust an $_POST[] value in an <input>. you need to fill in the <form ....> tag and add a submit-input...